# Sitecore EXM bounce email issue

Tags: exm

I am using EXM with Sitecore 9.0. I have issue with bounce rate, it is always zero. I am using custom smtp and configured pop3 details already. I have deliberately sent some emails to wrong email addresses. EXM is always showing delivered 100%, bounce rate 0%. Other reports like unique open rate, open rate etc are working fine.  I already gone through this [sitecore documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/exm/90/email-experience-manager/en/the-configuration-settings-for-collecting-bounces.html). I've enabled exm logging as well but no error logged there. I already set Undelivered max to 1 and pull pop3 bounces agent to 5 minutes.

Comment: Which mail provider do you use to send emails? Sendgrid or something else?

Comment: smtp - smtp.office365.com and pop3 - outlook.office365.com

Comment: In the  Delivery Status Notifications section on the manager root, have you ticked the 'Collect Notifications' checkbox? (and filled in the rest of the fields)

Comment: Yes, with other pop3 server details also.

Comment: Have you disabled the scheduler on the CM?  Bounces have a Schedule Task Item that is used to check the POP3 box.

Comment: It's enabled and I've few more scheduled task that are working fine.